# xsltproc merging xml files not working

Tags: xml, linux, xslt, merge, rhel

Hi I have to xml files to merge on the below condition:

Copy all the existing nodes of new file and then merge with old file values.
For example:

File abc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schedule>
    <Item Id="2">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>Alpha</measurement>
        </measurements>
    </Item>
    <Item Id="9">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>Gamma</measurement>
        </measurements>
    </Item>
</schedule>
```

File xyz.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schedule>
    <Item Id="1">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>Alpha</measurement>
        </measurements>
    </Item>
    <Item Id="4">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>Beta</measurement>
        </measurements>
    </Item>
</schedule>
```

xslt logic file:
logic.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:variable name="match" select="document('./abc.xml')/schedule/Item[measurements/measurement=current()/measurements/measurement]"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$match">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$match"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Command used:**

```
xsltproc logic.xslt xyz.xml > output.xml
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schedule>
    <Item Id="2">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>Alpha</measurement>
        </measurements>
    </Item>
    <Item Id="4">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>Beta</measurement>
        </measurements>
    </Item>
    <Item Id="9">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>Gamma</measurement>
        </measurements>
    </Item>
</schedule>
```

But actual is different then expected one which is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schedule>
    <Item Id="2">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>Alpha</measurement>
        </measurements>
    </Item>
    <Item Id="9">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>Gamma</measurement>
        </measurements>
    </Item>
</schedule>
```

It misses the nodes from the new xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$match">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$match"/>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

to

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$match">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$match"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:choose>
```

With the edit of the question and additional elements from the second document needed to be copied I think the problem is more difficult, with XSLT 3 you could do it as in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTf

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="doc1" select="/"/>

    <xsl:param name="doc2">
        <schedule>
            <Item Id="2">
                <measurements>
                    <measurement>Alpha</measurement>
                </measurements>
            </Item>
            <Item Id="9">
                <measurements>
                    <measurement>Gamma</measurement>
                </measurements>
            </Item>
        </schedule>      
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:key name="ref" match="Item" use="measurements/measurement"/>

    <xsl:template match="schedule">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Item, $doc2/schedule/Item[not(key('ref', measurements/measurement, $doc1))]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item[root() is $doc1 and key('ref', measurements/measurement, $doc2)]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', measurements/measurement, $doc2)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(of course instead of having the second document inline you would use `<xsl:param name="doc2" select="document('abc.xml')"/>`) but with XSLT 1 it is more difficult to work with variables and keys and you can't use them in match patterns so it seems an approach needs as in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTf/2

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">


    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="doc1" select="/"/>

    <xsl:param name="doc2-rtf">
        <schedule>
            <Item Id="2">
                <measurements>
                    <measurement>Alpha</measurement>
                </measurements>
            </Item>
            <Item Id="9">
                <measurements>
                    <measurement>Gamma</measurement>
                </measurements>
            </Item>
        </schedule>      
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="doc2" select="exsl:node-set($doc2-rtf)" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"/>

    <xsl:template match="schedule">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Item"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$doc2/schedule/Item[not(measurements/measurement = $doc1//Item/measurements/measurement)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="measurements/measurement = $doc2//Item/measurements/measurement">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$doc2//Item[measurements/measurement = current()/measurements/measurement]"/>              
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

of course again simply using `<xsl:param name="doc2" select="document('abc.xml')"/>` instead of having the data inline (which I only did to have a complete example and which unfortunately with XSLT 1 then requires use of a node-set extension function).

Comment: Thanks Martin for your reply.
But with this logic it misses nodes which are not present in the new file.
For example "Gamma" in this case which i just now edited.

Comment: So which document determines the elements you want to compare with the one from the other document? How do you determine the order of the resulting `Item` elements?

Comment: The order is to first copy all the Items from xyz.xml and then update/merge Items from abc.xml So that the final file contains all Items of abc.xml and xyz.xml. 
The final file should contain all items of both the xmls but the common items value will be overriden by abc.xml
Actually, this is a software upgrade scenario where we need to keep older version setting, merging common node values with older version values and finally adding new settings from latest version.

Comment: So why does the expected output have the `Gamma` element as the second element? Shouldn't that be added after the elements taken from the primary input?

Comment: @SambitMishra, I have edited the answer and added a sample that hopefully implements the merging and copying.

Comment: Great it worked as expected!
Thank you very much Martin :)